# Bootstrap grid system - how to make two columns with equal height?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make two columns having the same height in Bootstrap grid columns?

```css
.item-text {
  padding: 30px !important;
  /* Flex center. */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}
.item-text .item-center {
  align-self: center;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6 col-sm-12">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 item-text">
    <div class="item-center">
      <h3 class="heading item-heading">(Title) Ways of Something</h3>
      <p class="item-contributor">John Berger</p>
      <p class="item-description">(Short description) Remix-remake of John Berger’s 1972 BBC documentary, Ways of Seeing</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result:

[image]

Any ideas how to make the right column's height equal as the left one?

Comment: Have you tried: http://getbootstrap.com.vn/examples/equal-height-columns/ ? - Nice font by the way

Comment: @ThomasYates yes tried that but doesnt work...

Comment: You need to actually add the CSS to your code. It's not in the original Bootstrap. I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Check Demo **[HERE](http://codepen.io/jpI/pen/JRJJpb?editors=1100)**

HTML:

```
<div class="row row-height">

  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/400x600" class="img-responsive" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-6 item-text">
    <div class="item-center">
      <h3 class="heading item-heading">(Title) Ways of Something</h3>
      <p class="item-contributor">John Berger</p>
      <p class="item-description">(Short description) Remix-remake of John Berger’s 1972 BBC documentary, Ways of Seeing</p>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row-height {
  display: flex;
}

.item-text {
  padding: 30px !important;
  /* Flex center. */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 1px solid blue !important;
}

.item-text .item-center {
  /*  align-self: center;
    margin: auto; */
}
```

Comment: some extra space is coming in the image div, in this solution. Is it possible to remove that space ?

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to your CSS:

```
.row-eq-height {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
}
```

Then use that class on the row you want the column to have an equal height:

```
<div class="row row-eq-height">
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-6"></div>
</div>
```

That's it. This is the cleanest and more *official* way of doing it.

Comment: using this solution gives extra space in both the child divs. Any idea how to remove this?

Comment: @AalindSharma could you provide a Snippet or a screenshot? I do not know what you mean.

Comment: This style would interfere with smaller resolutions, meaning the cols will not go one of eachother in mobile resolution.

Comment: @media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row-eq-height {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
}